# $160$ people, $ 5$ leave in how many ways can this occur?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

There are $160$ employees at a meeting. During the last few minutes, $5$ of them quietly slip out the back door. In how many ways can this occur?

Would the answer simply be $P(160,5)$?

Or would it be: Since there are 160 employees at first anyone of the $160$ can leave. Then anyone of the $159$ can leave, followed by anyone of the $158$.. and so on. Therefore $160*159*158*157*156$ in other words $C(160,5)$

I think the answer should be $C(160,5)$ simply because the order in which they leave doesn't matter so it shouldn't be a permutation, but rather a combination.

Is this thinking correct?

Comment: You are correct, however in your third paragraph you are implying that $160\times159\times158\times157\times156=C(160,5)$ while that's the definition of $P(160,5)$.

Comment: Oops sorry I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the number of ways we can choose five people to exit in the last 5 minutes, where the order in which those 5 people leave doesn't matter, then we need $$C(160,5) = \binom{60}5 = \dfrac{60!}{5!\,55!} = \dfrac{60\cdot 59\cdot 58\cdot 57\cdot 56}{5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}$$

However, if the order in which the five people leave *also* matters, then we'd need to use $P(60, 5):$  And so there would be $P(60, 5) = 60\cdot 59\cdot 58\cdot 57\cdot 56$ ways in which this can happen.

Comment: OK, thank you! Just wanted to make sure I was thinking about this correctly.

Comment: @amWhy: Another ++++++1